# Reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at

Tags: rust

I am getting a lifetime error and cannot understand what the problem is. The code that's causing the error is:

```
fn fetch_git_repo<'a>(repo_info: &RepoInfo) -> &'a TempDir {
    let q: TempDir = TempDir::new("temp_git_clone_dir").ok().unwrap();
    //let path: &str = dir.path().to_str().unwrap();

    let status = Command::new("git").arg("clone").arg(q.path().to_str().unwrap())
        .arg(&repo_info.repo_url).status().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            panic!("Failed to run git clone: {}", e)
        });

    if !status.success() {
        panic!("Git clone failed!");
    }

    &q
}
```

And the error itself is:

```
test.rs:88:6: 88:7 error: `q` does not live long enough
test.rs:88     &q
                          ^
test.rs:75:60: 89:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 75:59...
test.rs:75 fn fetch_git_repo<'a>(repo_info: &RepoInfo) -> &'a TempDir {
test.rs:76     let q: TempDir = TempDir::new("temp_git_clone_dir").ok().unwrap();
test.rs:77     //let path: &str = dir.path().to_str().unwrap();
test.rs:78 
test.rs:79     let status = Command::new("git").arg("clone").arg("")
test.rs:80         .arg(&repo_info.repo_url).status().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                     ...
test.rs:76:70: 89:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 76:69
test.rs:76     let q: TempDir = TempDir::new("temp_git_clone_dir").ok().unwrap();
test.rs:77     //let path: &str = dir.path().to_str().unwrap();
test.rs:78 
test.rs:79     let status = Command::new("git").arg("clone").arg("")
test.rs:80         .arg(&repo_info.repo_url).status().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
test.rs:81             panic!("Failed to run git clone: {}", e)
```

What's the problem with this function?

Answer (score 4):

You're creating `q` in your function and then try to return a reference to it from your function. Since `q` ceases to exist at the end of your function, the return value would be a dangling reference, which is why the compiler won't let you do that.

btw. you can see that something dodgy is going on from your function signature. The lifetime of the returned reference (`'a`) isn't actually tied to anything (e.g. to the lifetime of a function argument), which indicates that this is probably not going to work.

Comment: If I change the assignment to "let q: &'a TempDir = &Tempdir...." it still gives me that error. How do I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to return a reference at all? Why not return `q` by value?

Comment: @hunterboerner, you cannot return a reference to a local variable at all. If you do, the variable is destroyed and you're left with a dangling reference - that's exactly what Rust aims to prevent. In C++ such code would likely give you a segfault.

Comment: @fjh the problem is that once the TempDir goes out of scope it will be deleted.

Comment: @hunterboerner The directory will be deleted when the `TempDir` is dropped, which doesn't happen if you return it from the function.

Comment: @hunterboerner It seems you've encountered a common misconception. Borrowing something never makes it live *longer*. If the borrow lasts longer than the thing that's being borrowed, that's a compiler error, not a way to make the thing live longer. If you want it to live longer than the function, then move it out of the function (e.g., by returning it).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by directly returning the TempDir.

```
fn fetch_git_repo(repo_info: &RepoInfo) -> TempDir {
    let z = TempDir::new("temp_git_clone_dir").unwrap();
    let q = z.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string();

    println!("{:?}", z.path());
    // omitted

    z
}
```